# Authenticate using OAuth to connect from external System to Salesforce

Tags: apex, api, integration, oauth2, authentication

Usually I provide partner wsdl to external system to connect with my Salesforce Org. Externla system call the SOAP API login() and get the session id. 
I am trying to implement Oauth as the authentication mechanism and 
I looked at - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm

I see the external system has to hit the endpoint - https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token , and passing the following, I will be providing them these details :

1. grant_type
2. client_id
3. client_secret
4. username
5. password

Obviously the external system has to store all the above values in their application. I read about below paragraph from OAuth article - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications where it says OAuth will be a secure way of connection because only access token is used and credential are not stored anywhere.

> Why Should I Use OAuth? For your end users the major benefit of OAuth
>   is security. If an external website's datastore is hacked and all of
>   their passwords are compromised, the hackers have full access to
>   sensitive user info. Instead of a user's credentials scattered around
>   various sites on the Internet, using OAuth the user simply issues
>   access tokens to individual websites that need access to their data.
>   If a site's access token and consumer secret are compromised, then the
>   user or provider can revoke them. In most provider cases a request
>   authorized with an access token is not authorized to update specific
>   aspects of the user's account, such as the password or email. With
>   Force.com, access to data is restricted by the user's profile and its
>   settings. Users can easily revoke a consumer application's access to
>   their data by revoking the token from their Personal Information page
>   under Personal Setup. For developers, OAuth makes life much simpler.
>   Gone are the days where you have to store your username, password and
>   security token in your application code or create bespoke login
>   schemes. Both of these methods are fraught with danger and cause
>   developers to lose sleep - if your application's security is
>   compromised or your code is decompiled, then every affected user must
>   be notified of the security breach and have their password reset. Not
>   only is this embarrassing but a security breach could lead to legal
>   actions. If your credentials are coded into multiple applications and
>   you happen to change your user's password, then you must undertake the
>   tedious task of updating each application with the new credentials.
>   Nothing is better on a rainy day than chasing down applications that
>   now have wrong credentials.

I feel that external system has to store the username and password somewhere and it can be compromised in this case. How does OAuth makes it secure? May be I have not understood it correct. If So, please shed some light on this topic.

**Update:**

There is no user interface involved in this connection and it is two system connecting with each other. SO there won't be any option to enter the userid and password by someone.

Comment: I am not so good in this but I feel it depends on how external application is getting the password. Generally, OAuth Flow provides a screen to the user and ask for Username and password, and then pass it to Salesforce with client Id and secret, hence not saving the credential. Later on, the app can use the refresh token to get the access. In case, the user is not involved then you need to store the password.

Comment: Yes, the user is not involved. It is two system talking to each other. Probably I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: hmm. If you can't show the login screen to the user and make an API call to get the token. You need to store the credentials. See if this helps.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138785/what-is-the-value-of-using-an-oauth-flow-for-your-own-external-systems?rq=1

Comment: That was helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com - best article on oAuth out there IMHO.

It discusses all available options. If not listed there then it will not be possible.

Now, if you do not have a way in the external system to have a user authenticate, you could build a visual force page for a user to authenticate and then grab the token. You could then provide the access and refresh token to the external system.

You would need to create a connected app and provide those details to the external system as well...

Doing this will allow the user to be able to revoke the token as needed and negate the need for the external system to store a password. Of course this assumes that the external system has properly implemented oAuth

Comment: The external system runs a batch to push data into salesforce nightly. There are no login page or a person involved when the integration runs

Comment: @SfdcBat - you do not need it when it runs, you only need it to perform the initial auth. It has to perform some sort of authentication and it can pass the client id, secret, and token you provide from your implementation on the Vf page oauth.